# how can I put a title on the colorbar in matlab output?

Tags: matlab

The output of my program is an area plot and there is a title of the figure But I want to put a title on the colorbar also.  i have searched many functions but I am not able to do this. can anyone help me ??

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is relatively easy to do using the handle output from colorbar:

```
imagesc(randn(10));
h = colorbar;
title(h,'my colorbar')
```

Answer (score 7):

In addition to Pete's excellent answer, if you want a label on the side of the `colorbar` use this:

```
[X,Y,Z] = peaks;
figure;
contourf(X,Y,Z,20);
h = colorbar;
ylabel(h,'Side colorbar label');
```

Comment: Actually, this works better if you have a long title for the color bar. Thank you.